# Reference a variable by name in C++ by using Symbol Table

Tags: c++, dlsym, symbol-table

Basically what the title asks.

Being a bit unfamiliar with `C++`, and the more advanced concepts such as symbol tables, I've looked into it online but am struggling to find any direction towards what my end goal is. Most of the tutorials I've seen cater to C, and the closest question I've found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254891/can-a-running-c-program-access-its-own-symbol-table)) puts me at a brick wall, as I've tried compiling it but I'm not getting the desired results, and I'm not too solid on how `extern "C"` works yet.

By the end of this, I want to be able to access a variable from the symbol table, and change the variable. I have played around with `nm` and `objdump` (and coming from a hardware background, it's definitely cool to look at), and I looked into `dlsym`, `dlopen`, etc. but I'm not sure how that could help me (especially since I've seen it used in C more than anything else).

Any advice or small snippets of code (so I can write my own sample program) would be great. Just to add, this is on a Linux system with a sort of outdated version of G++ (I'm not on the machine right now so I don't have that information) and I don't have access to upgrade it right now.

Comment: Pick a container that makes sense. Win!

Comment: key-value hints to a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example program that shows how to use `dlsym` to look up a symbol:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int my_variable = 42;

int main()
{
    if (int* p = (int*)dlsym(NULL, "my_variable"))
        std::cout << "my_variable @" << p << ' ' << *p << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "dlsym failed\n";
}
```

The `extern "C"` bit prevents [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B), ensuring the symbol table entry is simply the `"my_variable"` text passed to `dlsym()`.  You could not use `extern "C"` and provide a mangled name, but that would be compiler specific.

To compile the code, use:

```
g++ x.cc -o x -ldl -rdynamic
```

The `-ldl` is the library for `dlsym`, and `-rdynamic` asks not to discard symbol information for seemingly unused variables (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)):

> `-rdynamic` Pass the flag `-export-dynamic` to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of `dlopen` or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program

Output on my machine:

```
my_variable @0x401010 42
```

Comment: Thanks, @TonyD, this is exactly what I needed to get started on what I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

@TonyD has essentially the correct answer. For a more detailed discussion of how to use the shared libraries, [this is a pretty decent tutorial](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for this link, @ricecake, definitely helps out with a bit more in depth understanding of the functions and name mangling