# Get a function name from the symbol table at compile time

Tags: c, gcc, profiling

I know gcc has built in `__function__` and related macros, but from an outside function, if I'm being passed a function pointer, is there a way to get the name of that function out of the symbol table at compile time?

Basically:

```
void* foo(){
    profile_func(foo);
    do_something();
}

profile_func(void* func){
    printf("function is %s\n", NAME_OF(foo));
}
```

Of course, I know the symbol table is not an exact representation of the function, but it's enough to get the information I need.

I'm using `-finstrument_functions`, and this is going to be going in the related `__cyg_profile_func_enter()` function. I'm surprised that I can't find this already done by someone (unless my google-fu is lacking)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not in a way that's constant at compile-time, because in general, what the function pointer points to is not constant at compile-time.

If you want to get it at runtime, the `dladdr` function does what you want, subject to limitation that it may only work when dynamic-linked and is only able to find functions in the *dynamic symbol table* (so it won't find hidden, static, etc. functions). You could of course roll your own that looks at a more detailed debugging symbol table.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Would dladdr work within a dynamically linked library?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at compile time but it is not exactly well supported. You have to create the table on your own by running multiple passes of the compiler + `nm` or similar + some reformatting (e.g., via `awk`) as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255514/1905491).